# Uncaught ReferenceError when installing show more or less script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the code below from a [jquery script](https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Show-Hide-Long-Text-Max-Length-jQuery.html) demo to show more or show less text on a page:

```
<script src="js/show-hide-text.js"></script>

    <script>
        var th = new showHideText('.my-message', {
            charQty     : 250,
            ellipseText : "...",
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

I included their js file `show-hide-text.js` in my own js files compilation. I added the class to the html `<div class="my-message">content content content</div>` following their example.
I then call it by adding this to my js file too with others:

```
/**
 * 2007-2017 PrestaShop
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License 3.0 (AFL-3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
 *
 * @author    PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
 * @copyright 2007-2017 PrestaShop SA
 * @license   https://opensource.org/licenses/AFL-3.0 Academic Free License 3.0 (AFL-3.0)
 * International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
 */

import UIkit from 'uikit';                              
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min';      
import './plugins/jquery.lettering';                        
import './plugins/jquery.simpleTicker';                     
import './plugins/show-hide-text';                      


import 'bootstrap-touchspin';

import './checkout';
import './customer';
import './listing';
import './product';
import './cart';
import Form from './components/form';
import ProductMinitature from './components/product-miniature';
import ProductSelect from './components/product-select';
import prestashop from 'prestashop';
import EventEmitter from 'events';
import './lib/bootstrap-filestyle.min';
import './lib/jquery.scrollbox.min';
import './components/block-cart';


// "inherit" EventEmitter
for (var i in EventEmitter.prototype) {
  prestashop[i] = EventEmitter.prototype[i];
}

window.UIkit = UIkit;                                   
UIkit.use(Icons);                                       

$(document).ready(() => {
    //let dropDownEl = $('.js-dropdown');
    const form = new Form();
    //let topMenuEl = $('.js-top-menu ul[data-depth="0"]');
    //let dropDown = new DropDown(dropDownEl);
    //let topMenu = new TopMenu(topMenuEl);
    let productMinitature = new ProductMinitature();
    let productSelect  = new ProductSelect();
    //dropDown.init();
    form.init();
    //topMenu.init();
    productMinitature.init();
    productSelect.init();

    //Lettering
    $(".fancy-price").lettering();  

    //Category Page Toggle Filter Button Class and Icon for Mobile
    $('.green-btn').click(function() {
        var $span = $(this).find(".toggle-icon");
        if ($span.attr("uk-icon") === "chevron-down") {
            $span.attr("uk-icon", "chevron-up")
        } else {
            $span.attr("uk-icon", "chevron-down")
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("green-btn red-btn");
    });
    //Toggle Filter Button class and icon

    // jQuery.simpleTicker - Slide Effect
    $.simpleTicker($("#ticker-slide"),{'effectType':'slide'});  

    // Show and Hide More Texts
    var th = new showHideText('.minimize-text', {
        charQty     : 100,
        ellipseText : "...",
        moreText    : "Read more",
        lessText    : "Read less"       
    }); 
});
```

But it did not worked. Instead I got a **Uncaught ReferenceError: showHideText is not defined message**. I don't what i missed in following their examples

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you are using jquery then you have to include

```
1 - jquery.js
2-  show-hide-text.js
```

i just have disabled the other scripts in the code snippet to show you how its working in your code this scripts should be under `jquery.js`

```
$(".fancy-price").lettering();   
$.simpleTicker($("#ticker-slide"),{'effectType':'slide'});
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    // jQuery.simpleTicker - Slide Effect
   // $.simpleTicker($("#ticker-slide"),{'effectType':'slide'});  

    //Lettering
    // $(".fancy-price").lettering();   

    // Show and Hide More Texts
    var th = new showHideText('.my-message', {
        charQty     : 100,
        ellipseText : "...",
        moreText    : "Read less",
        lessText    : "Read more"       
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Show-Hide-Long-Text-Max-Length-jQuery/js/show-hide-text.js"></script>

<div class="my-message">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, cumque, modi. Sint dolore, fugiat asperiores, fuga nulla commodi delectus natus, beatae porro earum dicta. Culpa blanditiis quis adipisci recusandae mollitia.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium, cumque, modi. Sint dolore, fugiat asperiores, fuga nulla commodi delectus natus, beatae porro earum dicta. Culpa blanditiis quis adipisci recusandae mollitia.
</div>
```

Comment: I am working on Prestashop and it comes with `jquery` loaded. I included the `show-hide-text.js` before calling the script. The other scripts work well using this approach so I do not understand why this could not.

Comment: it will be helpful if you can provide a live link to see the problem

Comment: Currently working on local host at the moment. But I have edited the question and added my full template full JS file.

Comment: what about trying this  remove this DOM ready `$(document).ready(() => ` just put all the code without calling DOM ready